Equation of motion for Hamiltonian for n bodies.
Finding the arising equation of motion for given the Hamiltonian of n particles
$$H = \frac{1}{2m} q_n^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}(y_{n+1}-y_n)^2+\frac{\beta}{4}(y_{n+1}-y_n)^4$$
The $\alpha,\beta, m$ are constants. The $y_n$ is a displacement with momentum $q_n=m \dot{y}_n$ and $h$ can be used to represent the distance between any two states say $y_{n+1},y_n$.
I made the attempt using the Hamilton's equations
$$\frac{d {q}_n}{d t}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_n}, \qquad \frac{d {p}_n}{d t}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_n} $$
and the Euler-Lagrangian equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_n}\bigg]=\frac{\partial L}{\partial {q}_n}$$
for Lagrangian $L=T-V$, with $T=m\dot{q}_n^2/2$ and $V$ is the potential energy as defined in the Hamiltonian $H$.
The equation to be obtained should be something like
$$\frac{\partial^2 y_n}{\partial^2t}-\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{h^2m}\bigg) (y_{n+1}+y_{n-1}-2y_{n})-\bigg (\frac{\beta}{m h^4}\bigg) [(y_{n+1}-y_{n-1})^3-(y_{n}-y_{n-1})^3].$$
My results are not even closer to this answer. Any hint is  highly appreciated.

$q$ is the state in the EL and Hamilton equations, but it is the momentum in your equations. Was this corrected in your attempt?

Thank you @whpowell96. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. However, the question is correct. If I chose to write the Hamiltonian in terms of y only, we get $$H =\frac{1}{2}m \dot{y}n+\frac{\alpha}{2 } (y{n+1}-y_n)^2 +\frac{\beta}{4 } (y_{n+1}-y_n)^4$$ so the question narrows down to the involvement of the terms $y_{n-1}, 2y_n$  and so forth in the equation of motion. When I apply discrete derivative I never get close to answer. Perhaps, someone can refer me a literature I can read about such derivatives. Thanks

It is unclear how you are using $h$, so I will take it as a characteristic length scale. Define the generalized coordinate for particle $i$ to be $q_i = \frac{y_i}{h}$ and denote the conjugate momentum as $p_i$. Note that $p_i=h^2m\dot{q_i}$. Then the Hamiltonian of interest is $$H=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2mh^2}p_i^2+\frac{\alpha h^2}{2}(q_{i+1}-q_{i})^2 + \frac{\beta h^4}{4}(q_{i+1}-q_{i})^4\right),$$ where we understand $q_{n+1}=q_1$ to enforce periodic boundary conditions. Then apply Hamilton's equations to particle $j$ ($j$ is a free index as compared to the dummy index $i$ in the sum): $$ \dot{q_j}= \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}, \dot{p_j}= \color{red}{-}\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}.$$ From this, find a differential equation for $\ddot{q_j}$ in terms of the generalized coordinates $\boldsymbol{q}$ and finally cast this back in terms of $\ddot{y_j}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ to get the equation of motion for particle $j$.

Thanks @DarkLordOfPhysics.  This does not give me the desired result too. What I'm asking is how's the derivative of the terms is taken. For instance, how does the derivative of $(y_{n+1}-y_n) ^2 $ becomes $$\frac{1 }{h^2} (y_{n+1}+y_{n-1}-2y_n )$$ the Hamilton's equation can be re-expressed in terms of $y_n$, hence can give the same results in terms of $y$'s only. I know finite difference could have been used but I don't get this answer.

The idea needed to calculate $\dot{p_j}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}$ is that $$\begin{align*}\partial_{q_j}\sum_{i=1}^n(q_{i+1}-q_i)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{q_j}(q_{i+1}-q_i)^2\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n 2(q_{i+1}-q_i)(\delta_{j:i+1}-\delta_{ji})\&=2(q_j-q_{j-1})-2(q_{j+1}-q_j)\&=-2(q_{j+1}+q_{j-1}-2q_j).\end{align*}$$ It is unclear where the $\frac{1}{h^2}$ factor is coming from unless you are differentiating with respect to $u_j=h^2y_j$ which has $\partial_{u_j}=\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial u_j}\partial_{y_j}=\frac{1}{h^2} \partial_{y_j}$ or the quantity being differentiated already has it.

I think the latter is more likely because for the Hamiltonian you provided, the equation of motion you expect to hold only does when $h^2=1$. The choice of generalized coordinates will not change the EOM after it is cast back into $\boldsymbol{y}$ as you say. You will get the EOM you expect though using the modified Hamiltonian $$H'=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\left(\frac{(q_{i+1}-q_i)}{h}\right)^2+\frac{\beta}{4}\left(\frac{(q_{i+1}-q_i)}{h}\right)^4.$$​

Thank you. This helps a lot. So, the missing key is the use of summation in the Hamiltonian.

Exactly, the sum needs to be there to show that there is an interaction between every pair of adjacent particles. Otherwise, a lot of the $n$ particles would not be interacting with anything. In terms of the math, the partial derivatives of the Hamiltonian with respect to the generalized coordinates corresponding to non-interacting particles would all vanish, meaning their conjugate momentum would be constant as would be expected when there is no net force on them.
